# how do i change contents of html file in objective c when file load in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am loading google map streetview in my webview and i want i enter the location in uitextfield it should change the lat long of html file how can do that this is the code of html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Embedded StreetView</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
        var panoramaOptions = {
          position:bryantPark,
          pov: {
            heading: 165,
            pitch:0,
            zoom:1
          }
        };
        var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
        myPano.setVisible(true);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="pano" style="width: 425px; height: 240px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i am loading this html file in webview and after that i wanted to change the lat long after passing address in my  uitextfield but i don't know how can i change the html file on run time

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using javascript. For example, in order to add a new paragraph to the body by writing the following code:

```
NSString *js = @"document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(\"p\"));";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: but how i can pass the value of coordiates like location.coordinate.latitude and location.coordinate.longitude, i get these values in two string like string1 for lat and string2 for lon kindly tell you show me how can i pass string1 and string2 to this js file